# Comparable VS <? extends Comparable>

Tags: java, generics, java-8, extends, comparable

regarding the following code:

```
public class Test <T extends Comparable>{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> lst = Array.asList("abc","def");
        System.out.println(func(lst));
    }
    public static boolean func(List<**here**> lst){
        return lst.get(0).compareTo(lst.get(1)) == 0;
    }
}
```

why writing " ? extends Comparable" **here** would compile , and writing "Comparable" would not compile?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because generics are *invariant*. Even if `String` *is* a `Comparable`, meaning:

```
String s = "";
Comparable c = s; // would work
```

Generics of these would not work:

```
List<Comparable> listC = List.of();
List<String> listS = List.of();

listC = listS; // will fail
```

And this would not work no matter what is the relationship between `Comparable` and `String`.

When you change the definition of that method to:

```
public static boolean func(List<? extends Comparable> lst) {
    ...
}
```

This is said that: *wildcard with an extends-bound makes the type covariant.*

This means that :

```
List<? extends Comparable> listC = List.of();
List<String> listS = List.of();

listC = listS; // would work here
```

Or in simpler words it means that `List<String>` *is a subtype* of `List<? extends Comparable>`.

There is a small price to pay now, because `listC` is now a *producer* of elements, meaning you can take elements out of it, but you can not put anything into it.

And well after you understand this, you are not done yet, because the definition of that method would be entirely correct, when written like this:

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean func(List<T> lst) {
      .....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `List<SubClass>` cannot be cast to `List<BaseClass>`. Let us suppose that it could

```
List<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Comparable> cList = (List<Comparable>) sList;
cList.add(5);
```

This would be a problem because the integer 5 is not a `String` and should not be placed in a `List<String>`.

By using `? extends Comparable` you are saying that the function can take a list of anything that has Comparable as a base class (e.g. `List<Comparable>`, `List<String>`, `List<Integer>`, etc.)

To more correctly define your function you should do the following:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean func(List<T> lst) {}
```

This enforces that the type is comparable with itself. Your function compares the first and second element in the list, so it is best to ensure that each element in the list is actually comparable with every other element.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
List<String> lst = Array.asList("abc","def");
```

`lst` list has generic type `String`, not `Comparable`.
`String` class, hovewer, implement `Comparable<String>` interface, so it fits in `? extends Comparable` generic type.