# What means (List<?>) into the cast from a list of "generics" object represented by an interface to a concrete type implementing it?

Tags: java, java-8, interface, casting

I am working on a Java application and I have the following doubt about the propper way to conver a List of objects implementing an **interface** into a specific concrete object. I have the following code, it is working fine but I am not completly understanding the meaning of the syntax:

```
List<ExcelTabInterface> compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal =  excelService.getCompVibrAndTempTab();

List<CompVibrAndTempDTO> compVibrAndTempDTOList = (List<CompVibrAndTempDTO>)(List<?>) compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal;
```

As you can see in the first line I call a method to obtain a list of objects implementing an interface named **ExcelTabInterface**. So this list contains any object implementing my **ExcelTabInterface** interface.

Then I need to cast this list into a list of a concrete objects implementing my interface, I have done it with the second line. I am casting my original list into a list of **CompVibrAndTempDTO** (that is a class implementing my **ExcelTabInterface**).

At the beginning I expected that the code should be simply something like this:

```
List<CompVibrAndTempDTO> compVibrAndTempDTOList = (List<CompVibrAndTempDTO>) compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal;
```

but I disconverd that it can't work and that the correct way is:

```
List<CompVibrAndTempDTO> compVibrAndTempDTOList = (List<CompVibrAndTempDTO>)(List<?>) compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal;
```

Why? What exactly means this **(List)**? Why I need it to cast into a **List**?

Comment: `List<?>` is the super type of all `List` with any generic type, it is like `Object`, in a way

Comment: did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that generics are invariant, [here is the long explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224806/comparable-vs-extends-comparable/52225316#52225316).

So writing this, for example:

```
List<ExcelTabInterface> compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
List<CompVibrAndTempDTO> compVibrAndTempDTOList = compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal;
```

will not work.

But if you first assign to a "super-type" or "parent of all generic Lists" (I do not have a better name), then narrow down to a type, the compiler has to trust you (via a warning), because that could happen to be true:

```
    List<ExcelTabInterface> compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
    List<?> parentOfAll = compVibrAndTempDTOListOriginal;

    // a warning here
    List<CompVibrAndTempDTO> compVibrAndTempDTOList = (List<CompVibrAndTempDTO>) parentOfAll;
```