# Java Supplier<TYPE> vs Supplier<? extends TYPE>

Tags: generics, method-reference, covariant-return-types

I know it may have something to do with *Generic* and *Covariant return types*. But I can not make it through.

Given two classes where **Apple** extends **Fruit**.

```java
public class TestReturnValue {
    public static Supplier<? extends Fruit> conFruitExt = Apple::new;
    public static Supplier<Fruit> conFruit = Apple::new;    // Compiles
    public static final Supplier<Fruit> supApple = supplyApple(); // Compile ERROR

    private static Supplier<Apple> supplyApple() {
        return Apple::new;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit fruitExt = conFruitExt.get();
        Fruit fruit = conFruit.get();

        System.out.println(fruitExt);
        System.out.println(fruit);
    }
}
```

What is the different between *conFruitExt* and *conFruit*? They both are constructor of **Apple**, and calling `get()` create apple instances.

Does the additional `? extends` part of *conFruitExt* type make any difference?

Update1 2020/11/19

As suggestted answer says, [question mark in generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean) by  jonrsharpe, `Supplier<Fruit>` does not compile to `Suppier<Apple>`, so `public static final Supplier<Fruit> supApple = TestReturnValue::supplyApple;` does not compile.

But as method `supplyApple()`'s return value indicates `Apple::new` is type of `Supplier<Apple>`, why does `public static Supplier<Fruit> conFruit = Apple::new` compiles. Doesn't it assign a `Supplier<Apple>` instance to `Supplier<Fruit>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the question mark in Java generics' type parameter mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009745/what-does-the-question-mark-in-java-generics-type-parameter-mean)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not quite. Question description was updated for more details.

Comment: generics are [invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224806/comparable-vs-extends-comparable/52225316#52225316), for one example. Even if `Apple` _is_ `Fruit`, a `Supplier<Apple>` _is not_ `Supplier<Fruit>`.

Comment: @Eugene So why does `Supplier<Fruit> conFruit = Apple::new` compiles? Isn't  it something like `Supplier<Fruit> conFruit = Supplier<Apple>`?

Comment: your edit does not compile either. I think you are confused yourself what the question is now

Comment: @Eugene You are right. I fixed it with more errors. Orginally I think it's a question about Generics and Convariant. With your answer I realized it is mixed with * the type of method reference and lambda*. I fixed the description, so it seems reasonable. And I will rearrange the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

By doing this:

```
public static Supplier<Fruit> conFruit = Apple::new;
```

you are creating a *poly* expression in `Apple::new`. These are inferred by the compiler in the context of usage. Think about it: if I give you just `Apple::new` - can you tell me what that is? A `Supplier`? Or a `Provider` (may be such a functional interface exists), etc? Thus these types are concluded from the surrounding context in which are used. It's like the compiler did:

```
public static Supplier<Fruit> conFruit = (Supplier<Fruit>) () -> new Apple();
```

which is perfectly legal (this is not what happens, but to make it easier for you to understand).

In the other method you have told what the return type is, explicitly:

```
private static Supplier<Apple> supplyApple() {...}
```

it is a `Supplier<Apple>`. Since generics are *invariant*, the second assignment fails.

Comment: Which is “the second assignment”? The line `Supplier<Fruit> supApple = TestReturnValue::supplyApple` fails, because `supplyApple` returns a `Supplier` and a `Supplier` is not assignable to `Fruit`. Variance is not even involved. Perhaps, you fixed it in your mind to `Supplier<Fruit> supApple = supplyApple()` which would fail due to invariance, but that’s not what the OP wrote (and it’s not helpful that it is not the second assignment either).

Comment: @Holger good point, I somehow inferred that from the OP question, don't know why :/